# Is it possible to center a layout/view inside CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `FrameLayout` inside `CoordinatorLayout` to inflate my fragments which contain `RecyclerView`. The thing is, I want to display a progress bar when loading the `RecyclerView`, but the progress bar is always at the top of the screen under the `Toolbar`. I have tried various layouts, setting `gravity` or `centerInParent` but none had worked. So is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some research I failed to find a way to make this work, so in the end I did this:

1. Put the progress bar inside the CoordinatorLayout with `android:layout_gravity="center"`.
2. In the activity, make 2 methods to show/hide progress bar:

   ```
   public void showProgress() {
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

   public void hideProgress() {
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
   ```
3. In the fragment, get a reference of the above activity through `getActivity()`, cast it to the actual activity and call the necessary method.

   ```
   context = getActivity();
   ((MainActivity)context).showProgress();
   ```

EDIT: this seems to be fixed in support library 23.1.1

Comment: What was "fixed" exactly? And how?

Comment: @androiddeveloper last time I checked with support library 23.1.1, I was able to achieve the desired result as described in the question without using the "hack" in this answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's just that in my case, it's in the center only if the upper area is expanded, and I want it be centered when it's collapsed , because I made it collapse by default...

Comment: @androiddeveloper maybe using a `AppBarStateChangeListener` and setting a `paddingTop` to the `ProgressBar` when it is collapsed?

Comment: I've added margin (padding is also ok) according to what's in it. Now it's ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 73):

```
    android:layout_gravity="center"
```

works just fine.
And remove your FrameLayout, it's redundant.

Comment: `FrameLayout` is the view to inflate the fragment. Its not the outmost ViewGroup.

Answer (score 2):

I have created My View Like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/order_list_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/order_list_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/order_list_outstanding_amount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@android:id/icon"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_normal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_high"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/icon"
                    android:text="@string/format_outstanding_amout"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_large" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/order_list_recycler_view"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/order_list_recycler_view"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/order_list_empty_view"
            layout="@layout/empty_view"></include>

    <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
        android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        wheel:matProg_barColor="@color/colorAccent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: It might work if you don't use fragment. However as described in my first post I use a `FrameLayout` inside the `CoordinatorLayout` to inflate my fragments, which contain a `RecyclerView`, a `TextView` and a `ProgressBar`. In that case none of the gravity attributes works.

Answer (score 1):

Put the CoordinatorLayout inside RelativeLayout and add progressbar inside this RelativeLayout. Make CenterInParent for progressbar to true. Make progressbar Gone/Visible as per need.

Comment: In fact you don't need to put the CoordinatorLayout inside RelativeLayout just to make the progress bar center. The `layout_gravity` does that just fine. What I meant was the progress bar being in OTHER xml file, in that case it was impossible to put it in center.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to center a view inside another, you need to add constrainsts to all sides:

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id"
```

For the example below, I simply centered a TextView in the middle of a constraint layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a centered View"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result:

[image: centered view in coordinator layout]

Comment: Thanks but this question is no longer relevant with the current version of support library.

Comment: question is about `coordinatorlayout` not `constraintlayout`

Comment: @Zach so you just need to set `layout_gravity = "center"`

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout inside RelativeLayout and set CenterInParent  property 
to Progress bar.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myFrameLyt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, but the progress bar must be in the fragment's xml.